# Is concatenation of secure encryptions secure?

Tags: encryption, public-key, security-definition

If I have $n$ secure assymetric encryption schemes, is their concatenation $Enc_{k_1,...,k_n}(m)=Enc_{k_1}(m)||...||Enc_{k_n}(m)$ secure?

My intuition is that the concatenation is secure, but I can't solve it by reduction, which gives me the feeling that maybe an attacker can somehow take advantage of the combination of the encryptions.

The main security definition I'm interested in is the following - an encryption scheme is secure if for all PPT $A$ and function that maps public keys to messages $f$, the probability of $A$ to guess a random bit $b$ chosen uniformly when it sees $p_k,f(p_k)=(m_0,m_1),Enc_{pk}(m_b)$ is at most $\frac{1}{2}+negl(n)$, where the probability is over the coin tosses of $A$ and the public key $p_k$ generation.

Comment: This is an easy question if you consider how strong a chain...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-modelection - thanks for your comment. This is non an homework question, that's a question I thought about and couldn't solve. I didn't think my thoughts about it are so helpful, so I just posted the question. I also think that the existence of this question with answer in this site would help others. Anyway, I edited the question to include some of my thoughts.

Comment: @kelalaka - What do you mean by chain? And what is its strength?

Comment: That depends entirely on the definition of security.

Comment: @Maeher - Can you elaborate? I also added security definition.

Comment: As stated, the definition is unsatisfiable.

Comment: @Maeher - What do you mean? Is it generally unsatisfiable? I'm confused... (BTW - stated where?)

Comment: You have stated a definition of security that can't be satisfied by any correct encryption scheme.

Comment: @Maeher So Maybe I needed to add randomality over the keys. Then it would make more sense?

Comment: Are we talking about CCA secure symmetric ciphers, block ciphers or asymmetric ciphers? For asymmetric ciphers we would be in a bit of trouble if this was insecure, as anybody can generate different key pairs and perform encryption with the public key. It becomes a bit more interesting for block ciphers as e.g. TDES is relatively secure, but you can have weak keys and switch enc & dec. So this is where the "secure" definition is a bit on shaky grounds. Also, who is choosing the keys and algorithms? This may sound weird, but note that there is also IND-CPA where the attacker chooses messages.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-modelection - I talk about assymetric encryption (I did not know it matters here). As I wrote, in order to be not secure the attacker should find two messages for which it can distinguish between the ciphers.

Comment: Your definition does not match what you're saying in your comment. You're all-quantifying the messages. This means that on the one hand the definition is stronger because the message pair does not need to be efficiently computable, but it's also weaker because the messages cannot depend on the public key. You should really find the definition you're talking about and write it down.

Comment: @Maeher - I improved the formulation, such that the messages can depend on the public key. It basically the public key encryption security defintion from Katz & Lindell book, with a slight variation that the adversary does not have to compute the messages efficiently. If you better like the standard version, I'll be fine with an answer regarding this definition. To be honest, I would really like that someone will make some assumptions and answer my question.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption generally happens within a group. That group is usually not a power of two. E.g. in RSA there is a higher than normal probability that the first bit is 0 than 1, sometimes close to e.g. 90% if the modulus is relatively small (i.e. closer to 2^2047 instead of 2^2048 for a key size of 2048 bits), and that's assuming that the key size in bits is a multiple of 8. You'd expect the encryption to be well distributed in the group. Other asymmetric primitives such as KEM derive a symmetric key and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, generally the encryption with separate *unrelated* public keys of a plaintext message is considered secure. This is true even if you use the same scheme, but it is fine to choose other secure schemes.

If you combine these encryptions by concatenation then that's fine of course, assuming that you're able to deconstruct the result back into the separate encrypted values. This can usually be performed as the ciphertext size of each separate algorithm can be calculated as a function over the key size.

Consider the following proof by contradiction: if an adversary would receive $\text{Enc}_{k_1}(m)$. Then the adversary would be able to try and guess $m$ and construct $\text{Enc}_{k_1,...,k_n}(m)=\text{Enc}_{k_1}(m)||...||\text{Enc}_{k_n}(m)$ using the public keys of locally generated key pairs. If that would leak any information then the initial cipher would not be IND-CPA secure. This in turn would mean that no public key encryption schemes would be secure.

Note that indistinguishability is performed over the output domain of the cipher used. For asymmetric ciphers this is commonly a group, where the group size is not a two-exponent. This in turn means that at least the most significant bit of operations on a finite field has a skew to zero. As most ciphertext are in bytes, the topmost bits may actually always be zero. Similar issues may exist with the least significant bits (etc.). So the test you are proposing does generally not work for asymmetric ciphers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you clarify your proof? You try to prove that if all n schemes are secure, also their concatenation is secure, right? 

If I understood correctly you go from the contra positive - you assume that the concatenation is not secure and show it implies that one of the encryptions is not secure, right?

If this is the case, how do you know the adversary will be able to find m? From what I see it is not part of the assumption.

Comment: For CPA security the attacker controls the message. For all intents and purposes, the message could be a simple 0 or 1 so they would guess right by having two guesses. Even if the message is just one bit the attacker should not gain any information about the message, i.e. they should not know if they've guessed right.

Comment: The main point is simply that if the attacker could break the encryption by encrypting a message using a different cipher or key pair (under their control) that all asymmetric encryption is broken by definition. Encrypting a message using a key pair that they don't own is a weaker premise as now they don't control the private key. And since concatenation doesn't weaken the ciphers either the only possible outcome is that it must be secure. This is a bit of a tricky proof as it completely disregards the algorithms themselves and it only works if the ciphers are known secure.

Comment: It's not so much as a proof in itself. It is more a statement that **if** such a thing was possible then the algorithms would never be considered secure.